# How to speed up execution of Android UI tests as part of a CI system

Tags: android, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, jenkins, android-espresso

I'd like all unit & instrumentation tests (Espresso) to be ran after each commit / merge to the main `develop` branch. Unit tests are fast enough to allow this, but UI tests are not - 150 fully mocked UI tests take ~1h to run on a single device. [Shazam's FORK library](https://github.com/shazam/fork) does great job in sharding these 150 tests across all connected devices. The current solution is a local machine with Jenkins running on it. Connecting 4 devices to it reduces the time to run UI tests to ~15 mins. That's not ideal, but bearable.

Ideally I'd like to find a cloud based CI system that allows me to run UI tests using `Fork`, so that the local Jenkins can be ditched and not maintained internally.

I tried [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/) and [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/), but both are using their own systems to run the tests. It seems they don't give the option to shard a single test suite across multiple devices. They seem to be great tools to run **the whole test suite** on different devices simultaneously, but that's not what I want for a CI solution (to split the test suite to multiple devices simultaneously).

Tried [BuddyBuild](https://www.buddybuild.com/) as well, but internally their using Firebase Test Lab, so that didn't work for my case as well.

I was mainly thinking for solutions along these directions:

- find a way to run `Fork` on a cloud based solution
- find another way to shard a single test suite across multiple devices

Any suggestions are welcome! How do you guys solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot just split the single test suite into multiple? Then run them simultaneously?

Comment: That might work as a last measure - I'm afraid it might create too much overhead in maintaining some sort of a script to chop the suite into multiple pieces and then to combine the results from these into one. For a CI system I'd imagine automatic (or worst case one-step action to start the build) and then just get the results in one place.

Answer (score 9):

Congrats! Too much automation is a great problem to have. It sounds like you have already made a lot of progress speeding up the execution time. I'd say 15 minutes is a pretty reasonable number, but here are some alternate approaches to get that number even lower:

1. Create a smaller and faster test suite of the highest priority test cases to run per commit while the longer running full test suite runs continuously against the latest merged commits. This is a pretty common pattern across the industry. You can use Android's built-in [@Small, @Medium, and @Large annotations](https://testing.googleblog.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html) or package names to divide tests up.
2. Optimize your test cases so multiple features are tested at once. Essentially, instead of testing every combination like A1,A2,B1,B2, you would instead test only A1,B2. See the [pairwise testing Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) for a more detailed explanation.
3. If it's possible for your app, try using emulators. Performance has improved greatly the last couple years. Using Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) drivers I found tests ran faster and more reliably than on most physical devices. This could also make it easier for your goal to run in the cloud.
4. Check how long each individual test takes to run corresponding to its priority. A low priority long running test could be moved to a less frequently running test.
5. Watch the tests run to identify sleeps or other slow running areas of the test to improve.
6. Look for tests that have never failed. Those could also be another candidate for moving to a less frequently running test.
7. If you are looking for alternate ways to shard tests, you could roll your own by kicking off parallel scripts across devices that target a subset of your tests using [adb shell am instrument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) options. Although, this would create many separate test reports and you would need to evenly divide the tests up yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice summary of ideas to generally speed up the UI tests. I upvoted, but still looking for a way to run `fork` on a cloud based service. Otherwise I'll be stuck with writing custom scripts to run the whole suite in parts and combine the results of it.

Answer (score 2):

Might take a look at the [Flank open source project](https://github.com/TestArmada/flank) which seemed to be built with pretty much the same goal in mind: https://medium.com/walmartlabs/flank-smart-test-runner-for-firebase-cf65e1b1eca7

> Flank is a Firebase Test Lab tool for massively-scaling your automated Android tests. Run large test suites across many devices/versions/configurations at the same time, in parallel. Flank can easily be used in a CI environment where Gradle (or similar) first builds the APK:s and then Flank is used to execute the tests.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Machavity Thanks for the helpful comment, I updated the answer to include additional context, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Flank is at a very early stage and still has many bugs, but definitely something to follow and perhaps use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would also vote to the above suggestion especially item 1
"Create a smaller and faster test suite of the highest priority test cases to run per commit while the longer running full test suite runs continuously against the latest merged commits. This is a pretty common pattern across the industry. You can use Android's built-in @Small, @Medium, and @Large annotations or package names to divide tests up.
Optimize your test cases so multiple features are tested at on"

Using annotations and driving the execution through TestNG frameworks (via Jenkins) would be one way of splitting a large suite into sections - merging the results would also be less of a pain if the annotation management divides your tests by logical groups (hope this helps)